# MYSQL error logs in Windows when using MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am running an MVC4 application with MYSQL on WINDOWS, but am getting MySQL errors. Im sure there are MYSQL logs that get written to the directory .. However, I am unable to find it.

Please can someone assist

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Logs files are configured on the 'my.cnf' or ' my.ini' however, you can find easily where the Logs files are saved by querying the global variables on MySql.

Try this on MySql to know where are those Log Files

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE variable_name in ('general_log_file', 'log_error', 'slow_query_log_file')
```